# Eloquent Relationship stopped working and doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this two models below that have a 1 on 1 relationship. They worked like a charm but suddenly ( maybe because some updates in the database ( added 2 new columns )) it stopped working. I am getting the error only when I try to reach a payment that is part of a fare. For example.

```
$fare->payment->amount;
```

Gives an error: Trying to get property of non-object
When I use a DD(); to debug I see the following show up. [Pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin/PD8R8)

Does someone know what to do or how to solve this?

Below u can find the models

```
class Fare extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'fare';

    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Payment');
    }

    public function email()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getTimeagoAttribute()
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($this->created_at))->diffForHumans();
        return $date;
    }

} 

class Payment extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'payment';

    public function fare()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Fare');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Status');
    }

    public function scopeApproved($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 1);
    }

    public function scopeDeclined($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 2);
    }

    public function getTimeagoAttribute()
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($this->created_at))->diffForHumans();
        return $date;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but by default your `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are Carbon objects. So `getTimeagoAttribute()` can simply return `$this->created_at->diffForHumans()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it worked, I think you added a "payment" column in your table, so with `$fare->payment` you access to the attribute not the relation, you have 3 choices:

1. rename your column
2. use `$fare->payment()->first()->amount`
3. rename your relation

Comment: Ah I just figured it out mysql because the other answer here.. so it led me to the right direction but this was the exact issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is as given below:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

It rises when you access `payment` from `Fare` like this:

```
$fare->payment->amount;
```

According to your `dd()` result you have some `Fare` objects without related `Payment`:

```
// In your pastebin you have similar entries
["payment"]=>
NULL
```

So, in the returned collection you have some `Fare` objects without related `Payment` so this error is arising, make sure that the `Fare` object has a related `Payment` object before you try to access one. You may try something like this:

```
{{ $fare->payment ? $fare->payment->amount : '' }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Thanks to your answer I got it figured out. Your answer was not really correct but it helped me to get to the right direction. I added a column in fare table called payment.. really silly of me :)

Comment: Since you have `One-To-One` relation and you have used `$this->hasOne('Payment')` then you will get only one `Payment` object not a collection.